# Как передать значение H1 в форму

Tags: javascript, html, html-form

Вот так я успешно передаю  значение input в форму post

```
 <input type="text" name="name-1" value="" />

                    <div class="product_variant quantity">
                        <button class="button" type="submit">Заказать</button>
                    </div>
```

Как точно так же передать значение такого вида?

```
<h1 itemprop="name">
                        @Model.Name
                    </h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="modelname" value="@Model.Name" />
```